# Making Angular and Chosen Work with XHR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I have a web app that uses Angular and ChosenJs.  I have added a chosen directive as follows:

```
App.directive('chosen', function () {
  var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {

    scope.$watch(attr.chosen, function(oldVal, newVal) {
      element.trigger('chosen:updated');
    });

    scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function() {
      element.trigger('chosen:updated');
    });

    element.chosen();
};

return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: linker
};
```

});

Now I have a controller that is supposed to populate the dropdown, and uses the `$http` service

```
$http.get('/rest/stuff').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.stuffList = data;
  });
```

This XHR request works fine and produces an array of stuff, as required.  And in the html

```
<select chosen="" 
        class="form-control chosen-select input-md" 
        data-placeholder="Select an Option" 
        ng-model="theStuff" 
        ng-options="stuff.name for stuff in stuffList">    
</select>
```

Yet the dropdown remains empty.  How do I fix this?